# WCF REST Does Not Contain All of the Relative File Path

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I have a RESTful WCF 3.5 endpoint as such:

```
System.Security.User.svc
```

This is supposed to represent the namespace of the User class and is desired behavior by our client.

I have another endpoint I created for testing called:

```
Echo.svc
```

I am writing an overridden IHttpModule and in my module, I follow what almost everyone does by doing:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
```

If I make a call to:

```
http://localhost/services/Echo/test
```

My path variable has a value of '~/echo/test'

However, when I make a call to:

```
http://localhost/services/System.Security.User/test
```

My path variable has a value of '~/system.security.user'

In my 2nd situation, it is stripping off the '/test' on the end of any endpoint that contains multiple periods. This is undesired behavior and the only solution I have found to fixing this is some ugly string manipulation using the property which does contain the complete URL path:

```
string rawPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
```

This returns '/services/system.security.user/test'.

Does anyone know why my first situation does not return the rest of the URL path for endpoints that contain multiple periods in the name?